# How to keep PowerShell process open with input/output on runtime?

Tags: powershell

I'm researching these days on how to can I keep a powershell process alive so I can run PS code without opening a new process each time.

The need: - Running multiple PS scripts dynamically, so they have the same base (custom) modules, as efficient as possible.

Be able to communicate with stdout/stdin/stderr of these scripts process while it is still running.

Ideally I'd want one process to open with a docker, import my modules, and then collect the code itself to run, run it in the same process as the one already opened so it won't have to open another process nor import again my modules.

The problem: - Setting up PS process in a docker container takes tremendous amount of time. (Roughly 2.5s, before I have even begun to run any code, and I'm talking about the PS process alone)

As of yet I did not find a PS way to run dynamic code on the same process without creating a new process & importing my modules again. Nor did I find a way to dynamically communicate with the new process while it still runs.
Possible Solutions: - Create the initial PS process with -noprofile so it won't load so slowly. (I am yet to test this, but folks on redit seems to be approving of this method) - Use start-process with -NoNewWindow flag, so it will generate new process each time but I guess the initial setup time will be spared. - Trying to use Invoke-Expression on big chunks of code, but from what I understand that is not recommended and probably won't let actively communicate with the code running there until it finishes.

Start-Process -NoNewWindow
And

Invoke-Expression
Are the only relevant mechanisms I could find so far.

I've been told AWS lambda features similar functionality as what I am trying to achieve, but looking at it's code I did not make much progress, figured might be worth asking for help from people who are smarter then me :) Any help would be much appreciated. I do not seek for already fully working 3ed side solution, simply being able to mimic that behavior in PS code would be good enough for me.

Comment: cross posting is not allowed. select the best site for your question and remove the other post(s).